# adding external library to qt

Tags: qt, addition

I added the libardiscovery library to my Qt project by these two line :

INCLUDEPATH += /home/hosh/out/arsdk-native/staging/usr/include
LIBS += -L"/home/hosh/out/arsdk-native/staging/usr/lib" -lardiscovery

after that the Qt knows the #include 
and it knows the struct and variables of this library but when I call the functions of this library ,there is undefined refrence error in build step.

Comment: Looks good to me. Are you sure the lib is properly built?

Comment: Can you explain a bit more?

Comment: Did you check that the architecture of the library matches the one of your project ? (i.e. 32bits vs 64bits)

Comment: If you work with QtCreator you can right click on the project name and choose "Add library" and then QtCreator will guide you further. You can then use DependencyWalker (Windows) or ldd (Linux) to make sure the library was properly linked to your project.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer. The important point was that this library was a C library and I want to add this C library to a cpp project.to solve this problem we should add the libraries like this:

extern "C"{

```
#include <ardiscovery/ardiscovery.h>
```

}